# How to add image and text in segment in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-segmentation, segment

I am using bmoViewPager here i am getting only text in segment but i want image and text how to add in segment in swift like below.

[image]

only for text in segment i am writing this code:

```
func setMenu() {
    swipeMenuArray = ["Chat", "Alerts", "Starred"]

    contentView.dataSource = self
    contentView.delegate   = self
    pagerNavView.viewPager = contentView
    contentView.infinitScroll = true
    pagerNavView.autoFocus = false
}
```

please help me how to add image in segment in swift.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible using `BmoViewPager`, you might what to look into `Segmentio`

Comment: @Toto, okay then how can i achieve that, is there any other third party library to add image to text in segment. please help.

Comment: please read again my first comment. I gave you the alternative there **Segmentio**